# node-webkit enabling flag touch screen

Tags: touch, flags, node-webkit

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. If I use Chromium 34.0.1847.116 to enable touch events on my web app I have to:

1. start chromium with --enable-touch-events --enable-pinch
2. set to enabled the flag "Enable touch events" using chrome://flags

I'm looking to enable theses touch events on `node-webkit`. I'm using 64 bit version of `node-webkit v0.9.2` that uses `chromium 32.0.1700.107`.

If I add the following key to `package.json`, it does not work.

- "chromium-args" : "--enable-touch-events --enable-pinch" touch events on browser don't work.

If i try to open chrome://flags, I get a white page.

Is it a problem of `Chromium` version (32->34) or is it something else?

Thank you very much for your help.